# Canvas height to fit content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I asked a similar question and it got labelled as a dupe despite the supposed dupe not answering my question.

Edit: The dupe was [stackoverflow.com/questions/17211920/make-canvas-height-auto][1]

I am using a canvas to print a thermal receipt and as you might imagine the receipt can be varying heights depending on how many items are on it.

**I need the canvas therefore to adjust to the content.**

I know of `canvas.height = window.innerHeight` and similar but i don't see how this can help me.

**html**

```
<body onload='onDrawReceipt(shipment, returns, company, customer, img)'>
<form onsubmit='return false;'>
    <table id= "thermal-receipt-table" style='width:100%;'>
        <tbody>
            <tr >
                <td colspan='2' class='left'>
                    <div id='canvasFrame'>
                        <canvas id='canvasPaper' width='576' height= '640' >

                        </canvas>
                    </div>

                </td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

**js**

```
function onDrawReceipt(order, returns, company, customer, img) {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvasPaper');

if (canvas.getContext) {
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

        context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        context.textBaseline = 'top';

        lineSpace      =  20;
        leftPosition   =  0;
       //centerPosition =  canvas.width       / 2;
        centerPosition = (canvas.width + 26) / 2;
       //rightPosition  =  canvas.width;
        rightPosition  = (canvas.width - 0);

//      cursor = 0;
        cursor = 80;

//rest of code taking content to more than 640px in height.

}
```

Comment: You could perhaps include the dupe and say you tried what was specified. That would give other people more of an indication what you've tried.

Comment: provide a jsfiddle or pluckr example for people to play with

Comment: there's too much for me to be able to provide a fiddle and i really need help with this. Seems no way for the canvas height to dynamically change according to the content

Comment: You could calculate the needed height, resize the canvas, then draw the content.

Comment: yea, how would i calculate that? what elements would i use?

Answer (score 0):

You can rely on contentContainerNode.offsetHeight

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvasPaper')
var contentContainerNode = document.getElementById('myContentContainer')
canvas.height = contentContainerNode.offsetHeight
```